# Failed to use C++ Rest SDK and Microsoft unit test at the same time

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have a MFC project which uses C++ Rest SDK (`Casablanca`) under Visual Studio 2012 to implement an http client connection and it can be compiled well.
Then I add a Microsoft unit test project, but I can’t build the unit test project successfully.
In my main project, the environment is set as **“Use MFC in a Static Library”**, **“No Common Language Runtime Support”** and **“Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).”** And my test project’s environment is same as main project. The error message shows:

> “error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new[](unsigned int)" (??_U@YAPAXI@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(newaop.obj).”

In addition, I also try to change the test project’s environment to **“Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)” and “Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd).”** The original error disappears but new error comes:

> “error C1189: #error :  is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\atomic   line 9”

I do not know how to overcome these problems. Can anyone please give me some suggestions or resolutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CRT libraries use weak external linkage for the new, delete functions. The MFC libraries also contain new, delete functions. These functions require the MFC libraries to be linked before the CRT library is linked. Please check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652

Solution based on VS2005:

> go to project>properties>configuration properties>linker>input
>
> add to "Additional dependency" -> Nafxcwd.lib Libcmtd.lib
>
> add to "ignore specific library" -> Nafxcwd.lib;Libcmtd.lib

Comment: Actually I did this before, but it still failed with errors below.
> error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in Libcmtd.lib(typinfo.obj)
> error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that by using NuGet Packmanager to get rest sdk i.e. Search for Casablanca and select cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop. This makes sure all the dlls, libs required are referenced.

Please check:

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-use-the-C---Rest-SDK-NuGet-package

http://codename26.rssing.com/chan-8623770/all_p85.html